# Do duplicate registrations have bad consequences?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

Registering the same device with the same tags and template results in multiple identical registrations in the hub.

Will this cause a problem and will Azure eventually remove them?

It doesn't seem to result in duplicate messages sent to a device.

Answer (score 0):

I figure I can limit duplicate registrations by checking to see if they exist first using `GetRegistrationsByTagAsync`.

Even that method only takes one tag, so it's then typically necessary to iterate over all the tags for each registration to complete a match. Plus, the device token needs to be added as a tag because the registration base class doesn't have a "token" property. (**EDIT:** Actually, that doesn't work because it says the token is an invalid tag. So I'm going for one installation per platform - perhaps I could switch on the installation's class type to get the token value.)

Honestly, this API seems somewhat half baked. Even the newer installation based part of the API doesn't even let you download all the installations so you have to have some way of keeping track of them if you want to update them. If you have to keep a copy of this data then you may as well skip Azure altogether.

You can get the installations from the Azure tab in Visual Studio but once deleted, it doesn't seem possible to reinstall a device.

What a mess.